# std::set<T>::insert, duplicate elements

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, set

What would be an efficient implementation for a std::set insert member function? Because the data structure sorts elements based on std::less (operator < needs to be defined for the element type), it is conceptually easy to detect a duplicate.

How does it actually work internally? Does it make use of the red-back tree data structure (a mentioned implementation detail in the book of Josuttis)?

Implementations of the standard data structures may vary...

I have a problem where I am forced to have a (generally speaking) sets of integers which should be unique. The length of the sets varies so I am in need of dynamical data structure (based on my narrow knowledge, this narrows things down to list, set). The elements do not necessarily need to be sorted, but there may be no duplicates. Since the candidate sets always have a lot of duplicates (sets are small, up to 64 elements), will trying to insert duplicates into std::set with the insert member function cause a lot of overhead compared to std::list and another algorithm that may not resort to having the elements sorted?

Additional: the output set has a fixed size of 27 elements. Sorry, I forgot this... this works for a special case of the problem. For other cases, the length is arbitrary (lower than the input set).

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Is it "How does std::set work?", or is it "what's the complexity of std::set::insert?" or is it "what data structure should I use?" or something else?

Comment: Basically the answer to all three would be great, because I am not sure if I chose the right data structure for the problem at hand. The complexity of the insert is logarithmic, but it can be decreased if I can guesstimate the iterator position of the insert operation. I can also speed it up if I assemble all the elements and then I use a single call instead of a per-element call. I've read all that, but still I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing.

Comment: Guesstimating the iterator position is not good enough, you have to get it exactly right or it won't help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you think `std::list` offers here that would make it more suited to the task where `std::vector` would not?  In fact, since `std::vector` has random access, it would be a far better choice than `std::list`, since if you kept it sorted, you could use a binary search on it.  In fact, in some cases, this is even better than `std::set`.

Comment: @Mark.. then I'll drop the iterator position. The thing is, I may have as many as 10^6 of such sets, each of them constructed in a way I have described...

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Random insertions into a list will be cheaper than into a vector.

Comment: @Benjamin: the size of the sets varies, so I thought that using dynamical storage makes sense, for efficiency reasons (I didn't want to expand the vector if the size was to be greater then the capacity).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Hmm, you may be right, but I'll have to test that theory, since they're both O(n).

Comment: @Itjax: But first you need to find the position where the element goes.

Comment: @tomislav-maric: A vector is dynamic, and the cost of expanding the vector is insignificant when compared to the other advantages of using a vector.

Comment: @Benjamin: it is dynamic if I set the capacity to be large enough, otherwise I have O(n) to insert an element in case I exceed the capacity. For a special case (end set size == 27) this will work great.

Comment: It is dynamic, period.  It has amortized constant insertions at the end, even if you don't set the capacity.  It beats std::list at almost everything, test it.

Comment: @Benjamin: I'll definitely test it! From what I've read in the STL book, std::vector has O(n) for insertion if the capacity is exceeded. I'll test this as soon as I get the chance. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only have 64 possible values known ahead of time, just take a bit field and flip on the bits for the elements actually seen. That works in n+O(1) steps, and you can't get less than that.

Inserting into a `std::set` of size m takes O(log(m)) time and comparisons, meaning that using an `std::set` for this purpose will cost O(n*log(n)) and I wouldn't be surprised if the constant were larger than for simply sorting the input (which requires additional space) and then discarding duplicates.

Doing the same thing with an `std::list` would take O(n^2) average time, because finding the insertion place in a list needs O(n).

Inserting one element at a time into an `std::vector` would also take O(n^2) average time – finding the insertion place is doable in O(log(m)), but elements need to me moved to make room. If the number of elements in the final result is much smaller than the input, that drops down to O(n*log(n)), with close to no space overhead.

If you have a C++11 compiler or use boost, you could also use a hash table. I'm not sure about the insertion characteristics, but if the number of elements in the result is small compared to the input size, you'd only need O(n) time – and unlike the bit field, you don't need to know the potential elements or the size of the result a priori (although knowing the size helps, since you can avoid rehashing).

Comment: I'm not sure the OP has said that there only 64 possible values, merely that each set contains around 64 elements.

Comment: The 64 values are different, and the source data set is not structured in a unique way that would allow me to relate to the elements using the bitset.

Comment: In that case, I'd go for the hash table solution at the end of my answer. From what you described, that should have a good chance of being the fastest option.

Comment: @Oli: That's why I described what to do if that were the case and then continued with the other options if it isn't. Sorry if that wasn't really clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you're creating the entire set all at once, you could try using `std::vector` to hold the elements, `std::sort` to sort them, and [`std::unique`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) to prune out the duplicates.

Comment: +1, this is probably the axiomatic way of doing that in C++. It'll be very easy to implement and usually very fast.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of `std::set::insert` is O(log n), or amortized O(1) if you use the "positional" insert and get the position correct (see e.g. http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/).

The underlying mechanism is implementation-dependent.  It's often a red-black tree, but this is not mandated.  You should look at the source code for your favourite implementation to find out what it's doing.

For small sets, it's possible that e.g. a simple linear search on a vector will be cheaper, due to spatial locality.  But the insert itself will require all the following elements to be copied.  The only way to know for sure is to profile each option.